# api-ms-win-core-wow64-l1-1-1.dll on Windows 10

Tags: windows, dll, dependencies

I'm trying to revive some old software: it was developed on Windows XP, and I'm trying to get it working on Windows 10.

However, this software is dependent on `api-ms-win-core-wow64-l1-1-1.dll`, which isn't co-operating: [Dependencies](https://lucasg.github.io/Dependencies/) states that `api-ms-win-core-wow64-l1-1-1.dll` is missing imports, while Visual Studio's `dumpbin` states that it has no dependencies.

I'm aware that [Microsoft has migrated its functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-apis) and that [nobody should link to the implementations directly](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/a28331ae-19a3-4a34-b3ba-1e8fd4430375/missing-apimswincore-dlls?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues), but is there any way to get `api-ms-win-core-wow64-l1-1-1.dll` functionality for this old software on Windows 10? Alternatively, is there an accessible way to rewrite old `.dll`s to link to Microsoft's Win32 APIs?

(For those who need the file: I got `api-ms-win-core-wow64-l1-1-1.dll` by running `$ locate api-ms-win-core-wow64-l1-1-1.dll` on a linux machine with wine installed on it.)

Comment: API sets were added in Windows 7. Moreover, "api-ms-win-core-wow64-l1-1-0.dll" was added in Windows 8, and "api-ms-win-core-wow64-l1-1-1.dll" was added in Windows 10.  API set "DLLs" usually aren't files, except when supplied for down-level support, but rather they're entries in a API-set schema that the loader uses. For example, "api-ms-win-core-wow64-l1-1-1.dll" gets mapped to "kernelbase.dll" in Windows 10. Older utilities will look for a file that they claim is missing, but this isn't right.

Comment: Whenever I try to run the old program, I get the output `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Path\To\Dlls\MainDll.dll: Can't find dependent libraries`. If this isn't caused by a missing dependency, what could this be?

Comment: Have you find solution to this problem yet? I am compiling ffmpeg on Windows 10.  but I am still getting this missing dll problem.

Comment: @ErykSun So does that mean you can just copy and rename `kernelbase.dll` to `api-ms-win-core-wow64-l1-1-1.dll` to meet the dependency?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this directly addresses your issue.  I'm supporting a Java app which uses JNI with some native Windows libraries.  I used [Dependencies](https://lucasg.github.io/Dependencies/) to check what was missing and it turned out to be **api-ms-win-core-wow64-l1-1-1.dll** (through WS2_32.dll).

The solution for me was to install the latest [VC redistributable from MS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads).

Comment: That did not provide the dependencies I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Getting libraries from *Wine* is probably not a solution, in case you seek to use them outside the linux environment. (They are wrappers and obviously not using native Windows assemblies)

You can get some success by using extracting them from the [`ReactOS`](https://iso.reactos.org/livecd/) live CD. However, you should be aware that many of these are *umbrella* libraries, as explained here:

> An umbrella library is a single static-link library that exports a subset of Win32 APIs. For example, an umbrella library named OneCore.lib provides the exports for the subset of Win32 APIs that are common to all Windows 10 devices.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-umbrella-libraries
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-apisets
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-apis